# Email Link to open in any Browser and / or Client

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, email-client

I've designed a very basic landing page with a contact button.
I want to make sure that by clicking this button it will open the user's email client or webmail.

Is there a way to verify this or make sure it will work? I use Outlook, so in my computer it works.

This is the code for my button:

```html
<div>
   <a class="button-link" href="mailto:contacto@woodtechms.com">
 <button type="button" class="contact-button btn btn-lg btn-danger center-block contact-button">Contact us</button>
   </a>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: [mailto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) is a standard handler, **you** can not verify this, it will be up to the client's device on how the link is handled.

Comment: It should work in all browsers by default, except Chrome, I believe. And like @MattClark said, you can't fix that from your end.

Comment: @JeremyE. why do you say this does not work in Chrome? It absolutely does.

Comment: I had thought mailto links didn't work in Chrome unless you agreed to set Gmail as the default for the links. Perhaps they have long since changed that, or maybe I was never right.

Comment: Could have been just a Gmail thing and not pertaining to it working for other mail clients. Edit: it definitely was just having links work for Gmail, not Chrome.